# What on a server, would cause JavaScript in the HTML source to be stripped of comments and returns or new lines?

Tags: javascript, html, linux, apache, server

I have an HTML page with JavaScript in it and when I view the source of the page in my Browser(s), the JS comments are stripped out and the JS code is all on one line.  I will call this reduced code as it is not fully minified.  I do not want this.  I have told my host and he is working with the server guys but so far no luck in fixing.  The code is not reduced if the JavaScript has an error so I am assuming something on the server is validating the code and reducing it.  The same code on a different server is not being reduced so it is not my Browser.

Here is a screenshot of the code - I have downloaded it with FTP and it is still normal on the server so was not changed during uploading.

[image: Source]

Here is a screenshot of what I see in the source (it is the same in Chrome, Firefox and Edge).

[image]

Note: We are not using a CDN like CloudFlare.  It is an Apache 2.4.51 server on linux.

Any ideas I could suggest to the tech support?  Please keep in mind that I am not a server guy.

Comment: *as it is not fully minified* There's barely any there, but it looks minified to me, so that'd be the keyword to use when asking about it I'd think...

Comment: Thanks - adjusted the keyword - but note that it is not fully minified so just did not want to confuse. Cheers.  Also, why is there not a keyword for the source of an HTML page?  Or at least I could not find one.

Comment: "Page response payload" would be the one I'd use (where "response payload" could refer to anything you see under the Network tab in devtools)

Answer (score 0):

Ask them for an SFTP connection to the server folder where your HTML files are served from. Upload your HTML file to the server folder with FileZilla over the SFTP connection. This should hopefully bypass whatever server side javascript minification script they are running.

Comment: Thanks @mikemoy - the code is not being changed when I upload because when I download the file, there is no changed code - the file stays the same through the FTP process.  I have tried through Atom and Filezilla (sftp).  So I suspect it is being parsed just before it is served.

Comment: Doubt that,  a server technician would have to be a complete idiot to perform minification every time a file is requested. That would waste server processing power, if they want minification applied you spend the processing power once and server that same file ever time.

Comment: It would also intrduce pointless server lag waiting for the minification to complete each time before a file can be served

Comment: You could try include your javacript as a separate file to see if that works

Comment: Agreed, it seems like a bad idea but I just went to SFTP and downloaded the file and looked at it and it has no minification.  It is being stored on the server untouched.  Somewhere as it gets served the JS in the file is being stripped of spaces and comments - if I add an error in the JS it is not being stripped.  It is not the Browser as it does it on all browsers and different computers.  I am not using a CDN like Cloudflare so my question is what could be doing it?  I can then pass along advice to the server folks.

Comment: Remote JS files are not being stripped of new lines and comments.  But I have many html files with JS in them directly and it is a site for learning so people need to see the code properly.  This problem is new - the files used to show just fine but now all valid JS code in HTML pages is being stripped.  For instance https://zimjs.com/codetest.html is an example.  Hopefully, one day soon, this will show comments and new lines in the code but at the time of posting, it looks like the original source screenshot.

Comment: it could be an optional server module that is modifying the html file before serving for example Apache Module mod_proxy_html provides an output filter to rewrite HTML links in a proxy situation. Perhaps they have enabled additional server modules recently

Comment: Thanks, Mike.  The issue on the server has been resolved - I have just asked them what the solution was or the cause.  Will report here when I get an answer.